# Cómo generar una pirámide invertida en C++?

Tags: c++

Mi código debe imprimir una pirámide invertida pero en orden n filas, n-1 filas y así pero hace una salto de 1 # a 3 #

```
#include<stdio.h>
# include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

int main ()
{
int n, j,i;
do {
cout << "Introduce un numero entre 1 y 100: ";
cin >> n;
}
while(n<1 || n>100);

for ( j=n-2; j>=0; j--)
 {
for ( i=0; i<n-j-1; ++i)
cout << "";
for ( i=0; i<2*j+1; ++i)
cout << "*" ;
cout << endl ;
}
}
```

Le doy el valor de 7 e imprime :

```
###########
#########
#######
#####
###
#
```

y debe imprimir el 7 filas que se van restando de uno en uno al ir bajando:

```
#######
######
#####
####
###
##
#
```

Comment: Si te piden una pirámide.... ¿no debería tener el pico en el centro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
# include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

int main ()
{
int n, j,i;
do {
cout << "Introduce un numero entre 1 y 100: ";
cin >> n;
}
while(n<1 || n>100);

for ( j=n; j>0; j--){
for ( i=0; i<j; ++i){
cout << "*" ;
}
cout<< endl;
}

}
```

Básicamente solo necesitabas 2 ciclos, el primero controla la cantidad de filas que deben formarse la cual debe ser el valor de la variable n, mientras que el segundo ciclo es el que se encargara de imprimir los asteriscos, por cada vuelta de ciclo imprimirá la cantidad de asteriscos de acuerdo al valor que tenga la variable j en esta iteración.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 7;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<n-i;j++){
          printf("#");    
    }
printf("\n");
   }

}
```

Comment: Es hacer una pirámide..

Comment: Por favor explica el código que has puesto para que sea considerado una respuesta de calidad. Las respuestas en las que solo se deja el código sin explicar lo que hace son consideradas de baja calidad por la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución es inicializar una línea con 13 "#", imprimirla, reemplazar "#" por " " en ambos extremos, imprimirla, y asi sucesivamente:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char fila[] = "#############";
    int n = 7;
    int m = 6;
    for (int i = n  - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        fila[m - i] = fila [m + i] = ' ';
        printf("%s\n", fila);
        }
}
```

produce:

```
 ########### 
  #########  
   #######   
    #####    
     ###     
      #
```

Comment: ¡Me encanta tu solución! :D pero solo tiene 1 problema, la variable int i, debes declararla fuera de for.

O al menos a mí en DevC++ no me me la acepta ;)

Comment: @Ema. No conozco DevC++. Lo probe con Netbeans y on line:[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3LbsJADEX3/oqrIERQm6ohUbtI4UdKF6M8jSYz6SRhQcW3B0@iAt7Yxz4zN@@6KNfK1NO0YpPrsSi/@qFg@9YciNgMaBWb8Gy52OKPIJU3yqFirb5/sEeweq4gmxX/zsjx84Gt4MeClXUI/Y5lZ4AIcSbzAe/Soug/Z1Z9TCsG@yxPEHxZcINNdjc7Jz9WYbDujyZ4ndXt43ql6zQpU7iyB/V2sBQjppN1dUlu5AvtsCOnRr1QgkTodyz1IqdIbw "C++ (clang) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Candid_MOE Gracias por el recurso, no lo conocia! ^^

Answer (score 0):

Ni siquiera necesitas bucles para una pirámide así, usa recursión:

```
std::string piramide(unsigned piso)
{
    if (piso == 0)
        return {};
    else
        return std::string(piso, '#')
            .append(1, '\n')
            .append(piramide(piso - 1));
}
```

Comment: como siempre un placer ver tu codigo.